# AutoFill textbox on userform with exact value

Tags: excel, vba, forms, userform, vba6

I want to auto fill two textboxes on my userform ,from a data of a sheet i have, but i want the code to find with the exact value and not just one part of it.

Ex: if i put the number "33" it returns a value, when the column have like "202409334", i want to assume a value only when the entire number is filled.

```
Private Sub txtdevolução_AfterUpdate()



Dim id As String, rowcount As Integer, foundcell As Range


id = txtdevolução.Value
    
    rowcount = Sheets("retornos pendentes").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    With Worksheets("retornos pendentes").Range("A1:A" & rowcount)
        Set foundcell = .Find(what:=id, LookIn:=xlValues)
        
        If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then
            txtclienteopl.Value = .Cells(foundcell.Row, 3)
            txtmatricula2.Value = .Cells(foundcell.Row, 12)
         Else
            txtclienteopl.Value = ""
            txtmatricula2.Value = ""
            
        End If
        
    End With
    


End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, so what specific problem did you run into with your attempt?

Comment: Add `LookAt:=xlWhole` to Find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fill Userform Textbox

- The current error was detected by CDP1802 in the comments namely you need to set the `LookAt` argument's parameter to `xlWhole` to not get partial matches.
- Another issue is `With Worksheets("retornos pendentes").Range("A1:A" & rowcount)` when you later use `.Cells(foundcell.Row, 3)`. With the search column being column `A` it works, but if you would change it, it would return the values from the wrong columns. Implementing `.EntireRow` with `.Columns` makes it more flexible and allows the use of the more user-friendly column strings.

```vb
Private Sub txtdevoluçao_AfterUpdate()

    Const WS_NAME As String = "retornos pendentes"
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const CLIENTEOP_COL As String = "C"
    Const MATRICULA_COL As String = "L"
    
    Dim rg As Range, fCell As Range, lCell As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WS_NAME)
        Set fCell = .Range(FIRST_CELL) ' First
        Set lCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, fCell.Column).End(xlUp) ' Last
        Set rg = .Range(fCell, lCell)
    End With
    
    ' Reusing the variable...
    Set fCell = rg.Find(txtdevoluçao.Value, lCell, xlFormulas, xlWhole) ' Found
    ' ... short for:
    'Set fCell = rg.Find(What:=txtdevoluçao.Value, After:=lCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole) ' Found
   
    If fCell Is Nothing Then
        txtclienteopl.Value = ""
        txtmatricula2.Value = ""
    Else
        With fCell.EntireRow
            txtclienteopl.Value = .Columns(CLIENTEOP_COL).Value
            txtmatricula2.Value = .Columns(MATRICULA_COL).Value
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, never thought about that.